# Is it possible to get width of multiple <span> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a couple of `<span>` elements that are being generated dynamically. The thing is that I need to know their width together. I tried to wrap them with `<div>` and made `alert($("#spanWrap").width());` but it gave width of container instead of `<span>` elements.

I think I can try to explain it best by jsFiddl'n it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XGynv/7/

Comment: Divs will, by default, expand to take the width of their container. If you need them to shrink to the width of their contents one option is to make them float. http://jsfiddle.net/M4hWu/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `display: inline-block;` to the style of your div wrapping the spans.

---

**edit**:

with the spans wrapped in a div as in

```
<div id="spanwrapper">
   <span>span1</span>
   <span>span2</span>
</div>
```

the css style should contain (in this order, see comments by gilly3):

```
#spanwrapper {
   display: inline-block;     // the div shrinks to fit around the content
}

#spanwrapper {
   *display: inline;          // adding support for IE7 or lower
}
```

so that you get the width using jquery:

```
$("#spanwrapper").width();
```

or using conventional javascript:

```
document.getElementById('spanwrapper').clientWidth;
```

note that with the size defined by the browser, it now does not make sense to define a fixed width in the style.

Comment: Be careful applying inline-block to a div if you plan on supporting IE 7.

Comment: Inline-block in IE5.5 - IE7 can only be applied to inline elements.  So if you apply inline-block to a div, the div's display remains as block.  There is a trick that makes it work, but using it carelessly can mess up other browsers: First set the div to inline-block.  Then, in a later style declaration, set it to inline.  With this trick, the div will display as inline-block in IE7, but inline in newer browsers.

Comment: so adding display: inline below inline-block as in my edit above makes the solution generally valid?

Comment: No.  You have to put the `display: inline;` in a separate declaration block.  Eg, `#x { display: inline-block; } #x { display: inline; }`.  Then you have to put the second declaration in IE only code, such as by using conditional comments, else other browsers will all be `inline` instead of `inline-block`.

Comment: OK; I checked [here](http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced) and [here](http://www.conditional-css.com/demo/advanced.css) that conditional statements can be used for a single line within a css block, so '[if lte IE 7]' in the same block should do the job as well.

Comment: Have you tested this?  It doesn't work.  That link goes to a tool which generates conditional css for you, it is not valid css.  You need the second statement in a separate declaration block.  An easy IE7 and below only syntax is to prefix the attribute with a `*`.  Ie, `*display: inline`.  View this jsfiddle and play with moving the statements around into different declaration blocks, and with the different IE version modes.  http://jsfiddle.net/XGynv/19/

Comment: played with and added your suggestion; problem is I dont get my IE9 to show the fiddle page correctly (am a Chrome user) let alone switch to IE7 mode, so I trust you. Also [read](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Star_Html_Hack) about using '* html #divMenuSpan{..}' but am not sure if that is only valid for IE6 and for IE7 '*+html *divMenuSpan{..}' would work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can do it unless you write your own code to add up width of each span like below.

```
var w = 0;
$("#divMenuSpan span").each(function(){
  w += $(this).width();
});

//Now w will have the combined width of all the spans inside divMenuSpan
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an obvious answer but you could just do -

```
parseInt($("#fashion").width()) + parseInt($("#wedding").width())
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier if you just changed that container to a span instead of a div

```
<span id="divMenuSpan">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XGynv/8/

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGynv/11/).

Basically I am looping through the spans and summing the widths.

Answer (score 1):

That is because a div is a block element and block elements always fill the width of their container.  To make a div fit the width of its contents, float it:

http://jsfiddle.net/XGynv/12/

```
#wrap
{
    width: 666px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#divMenuSpan
{
    float: left;
}
```

**Edit:** I should point out that if your spans wrap, the width of the floated container div will shrink using this technique.  If you want the actual width of the spans, you'd have to iterate the divs in a loop and add up the sum of their widths.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var size = 0;
$('span.someclass').each(function(el) { size += $(el).width(); });
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can write javascript codes to calculate it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var spans = $("span"),   //span collection
        width = 0; 
    spans.each(function(index,ele){
        width = width + $(ele).outerWidth(true); //here, it will include margin.
    });
    console.log(width);
});​
```